# Web Api not working when deploy VS 2019 500 internal error

Tags: c#, json, postman, webapi

I'm fairly new to Web APIs and although I've read the responses for similar issues faced, I'm still sitting with errors.

I'm using VS 2019, MS SQL Enterprise, and Postman to pass the Json file to the endpoint.

Even with the below test code it still throws 500 internal errors (obviously an unhandled error). I've been pulling my hair out, and I'm sure it's probably a simple error which I can't see

NB: When I deploy to the server, the website is being hit according to IIS logs

**VS Code**

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
                using (DynatraceEntitiesPerson db = new DynatraceEntitiesPerson())
                {
                    var listPerson = db.PersonTests.ToList();
                    var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listPerson);
                    return strJson;
                }
            }
        
            public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] object personTest)
            {
                try
                {
                    var JsonPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonTest>(personTest.ToString());
                    using (DynatraceEntitiesPerson db = new DynatraceEntitiesPerson())
                    {
                        db.PersonTests.Add(JsonPerson);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        db.PersonTests.ToList();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"error " + ex.InnerException);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"person added");
            }
        }
```

**Model based on DB**

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class PersonTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**POSTMAN**
**Body | Raw | Json Format**

```
{
    "Name": "3",
    "Surname": "tester3"
}
```

**MS SQL table**

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonTest](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [Surname] [varchar](20) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

[image: Localhost working no error]

[image: Server Error]

[image: Log on Server. all pretty much similar]

[image: ISS Authentication]

[image: ISS Allowed protocols - HTTP only]

[image: Updated code to test SQL permissions]

Comment: I would expect to see an exception in the logs. If you're not seeing that, then fixing the observability problem should be the top priority. If there *is* an exception, please add it to the question.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet is referring to the Windows event logs (the Application log in particular), in case you go looking in the IIS log (although the error sub-code from that could also be useful).

Comment: Does the IIS service account have permission to access te database?

Comment: @stuartd I will check and revert back ASAP

Comment: You are using https (secure) which means a TLS authentication is used to make the connection. The TLS authentication occurs before the request is sent. The exceptions says no response was returned. Normally when you send a request you will get back a 200 OK for a good response or a 400/500 error response. You are not getting any response which is most likely due to the TLS authentication failing. You have to use TLS 1.2/1.3. (1.0/1.1 is not long be used. So try adding at beginning of code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: @stuartd - I think its SQL permissions from IIS. I asked the admin to add the following account IIS AppPool\HIDDENPoolName}. Is this the correct way?

Comment: @stuartd I replaced the account in the APP Pool with the account I run locally, which has access to SQL. Ideally, this should be a service account. But I'll test first

Comment: Great guys ...Thanks to all its working. It was SQL permissions but the APP Pool part of it. :)